# Warning: DocumentRoot does not exist... But it does

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to host 3 sites with Apache in Ubuntu 20.04 but when I try connecting to them I get

> Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server.

This is my virtual host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName nico1.com
        Redirect permanent / https://nico1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName nico1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/index1.html
        <Directory /var/www/index1.html>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/nico1.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/nico1.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName nico2.com
        Redirect permanent / https://nico2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName nico2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/index2.html
        <Directory /var/www/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/nico2.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/nico2.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName nico3.com
        Redirect permanent / https://nico3.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName nico3.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/index3.html
        <Directory /var/www/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/nico3.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/nico3.key
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I run `systemctl status apache2` I get

> Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/index1.html] does not exist
> Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/index2.html] does not exist
> Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/index3.html] does not exist

This is clearly the error here but I don't know how to solve it. I have already tried changing permissions and making www-data the owner of the files in the past and I've also set /var/www/ in this directive in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

These are currently the permissions of the files

> -rw-r--r--  1 alumno root  499 Mar  5 19:07 index1.html
> -rw-r--r--  1 alumno root  110 Mar  6 11:55 index2.html
> -rw-r--r--  1 alumno root  110 Mar  5 19:09 index3.html

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. The `DocumentRoot` parameter for a virtualhost must be a directory, and not a file! Create 3 subdirectories nico1, nico2, nico3, and move the correct index inside (you should probably rename it from index?.html to index.html)

See [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).